# Self Heating of LED

Tags: led, spice, semiconductors

I am using Red LED connected to B2902A SMU which can display current Voltage curve only.But i need to find out what is the temperature(Self heating) and how to find it using I/V curve.So that i can determine Heating dynamics Of LED.
Please help.
Thank you

Comment: So, what methods are you considering?

Comment: @Andyaka  i am extracting Delta current from ramp up and rand down current.Now i have Delta I for voltage range say(2-2.8v).It is all the information i got. And yea diode equation.

Answer (score 1):

The heating power is voltage times current.  The temperature rise is that heating power times the thermal resistance from the junction to ambient.

Comment: Having initial junction temperature has 25 degree celsius at initial voltage (say 2v) and how to get the final temperature at say 2.8v? I have no information about thermal resistance from my spice model( diode in series with resistance).

Comment: @maxy: Without the thermal resistance you can't know temperature.

Comment: Now i have power at each I/v point with respect to time.can that help?